# How to drag an item in a GridView and drop to another item?

Tags: android, gridview, drag-and-drop

I have a gridview. 
I want to drag an item that contains textview and drop to another item. and on drop their text will swap.

The dragged text will be transferred to the item where the text is dropped and the text where the item is dropped will be transferred to the item where the text is dragged.

```
droppeditemtext = draggeditemtext

draggeditemtext = droppeditemtext
```

Can somebody help me on how to do this or provide simple explanation on how to use drag and drop?

I saw some tutorials but they are complicated and hard for me to understand.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html

Comment: Qt's drag and drop tutorials were easy for me to understand so if you have enough time try them.